# How can I continue text from where div ends with bootstrap or html

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

In a div I put on the right with Bootstrap, I want the outer text to continue where the text inside the div ends. [the shape I want is in the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F28Z0.png). how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can float the image to the right, and not clear the float after. Any text after the image will wrap to the next line.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

</head>

<body class="m-4 border">
  <div>
    <h2 class="p-4 border-bottom">Title</h2>
    <div class="p-4">
      <img src="https://data.whicdn.com/images/323513059/original.jpg" alt="Random Image" style="height: 300px; width: auto;" class="float-end">
      <p>
        Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur arcu erat,
        accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultricies ligula sed magna dictum porta. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum
        sed sit amet dui. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Nulla porttitor accumsan
        tincidunt. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Pellentesque
        in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet
        et, porttitor at sem. Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Donec rutrum congue leo eget malesuada. Pellentesque in ipsum id orci porta dapibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec
        velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem.
        Curabitur aliquet quam id dui posuere blandit. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vestibulum ac diam sit amet quam vehicula elementum sed sit amet dui. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at
        sem. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Proin eget tortor risus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
        elit. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.
        Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Donec sollicitudin molestie malesuada. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor sit amet aliquam vel,
        ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla quis lorem ut libero malesuada feugiat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Donec velit neque, auctor
        sit amet aliquam vel, ullamcorper sit amet ligula. Curabitur non nulla sit amet nisl tempus convallis quis ac lectus. Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```